# Android: Alert Dialog with CheckedTextView

Tags: android

Ok guys..I have a problem...
I need to create a dialog with 3 CheckedTextView. And when i open a dialog, second item should be checked...How to do that ? Code ...

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);            
        builder.setTitle("Something..");
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);


        ListView listView = new ListView(this);

        listView .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(Settings.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, new String {a ,b, c}));

        builder.setView(listView );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

check adding check boxes and radio buttons , 
One method would be ,

Have a flag through which you can decide 
which to check next time when you popup the dialog and set the radio button in code ,
get radio button view and use toggle()

Check radio buttons and checkbox,

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html

Another method would be to use CheckBoxPreference.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this listView.getAdapter().getItem(1);. if your 2nd list item is check box, then set it checked by setChecked(true);